# Endless ViewPager: setCurrentItem(int pos) blocks UI when new position is less than current by at least 2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, endlessadapter

When I call `setCurrentItem(int pos)` method on `ViewPager` with endless items, `UI` gets blocked if the new position is less than current by at least 2. If the new position is less by 1 or greater than the old position the `ViewPager` works properly. For testing purpose I changed max number to 300, `UI` was not blocked. It looks like `ViewPager` iterates through items count to match the new position with them, in my case item count is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The `UI` block lasts for about 20-30 seconds and then it goes to the needed position correctly. Here is the adapter

```
public class DateCountVPAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public DateCountVPAdapter(Date startDate, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.startDate = startDate;
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startDate);
}

private Date startDate;
private Calendar calendar;

@Override
public DateCountVPFragment getItem(int position) {
        Calendar currentDate = (Calendar)calendar.clone();
        currentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, position);
        return DateCountVPFragment.newInstance(startDate, currentDate.getTime());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

}

I also tried to extend `ViewPager` and to amend `setCurrentItem(int pos)` method, however there were private methods which made impossible to do so. Also I tried to copy the class, however an issue with `PagerAdapter`, which had package private method used by `ViewPager`. Please offer any solutions to avoid `UI` block. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `setCurrentItem(int pos)` implicitly calls that the view transition should be animated as a smooth scroll if the `ViewPager` has already been through its first layout with the current adapter. So some of your time locked may be from the `ViewPager` attempting to draw smooth scrolling between your screens, especially if it has to create `Fragment`s in the transition.

Your first step should be using `setCurrentItem(int pos, boolean smoothScroll)` unless you really care about the smooth scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but it is not related to the transition, I have already tried it. It actually hangs in `populate(int newCurrentItem)` method of `ViewPager` in the following loop: `for (int pos = mCurItem + 1; pos < N; pos++) {}` where `N` is `Integer .MAX_VALUE`. I guess I will use `RecyclerView` instead... It would be better if there was a checking in the `ViewPager` whether new position is less than the old one, in order to use reversed loop.

Comment: If you must use ViewPager, I'd recommend going with a smaller value. You could go much smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE and still have what would appear to the end user to be endless scrolling.

I had a similar instance recently where it was a carousel on a number of items and did collection size * 1000. It was much smaller than the max int, which led to the time needed to walk through quite a bit smaller. In the case of a calendar, assuming you start at MaxInt/2, you have almost 3 million years in each direction.